# Multitenant Web App with Asp .NET Core Sign in Issue

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant

I am getting below error after I set application for multitenancy. An
unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. 
>   Issuer:
>   'https://sts.windows.net/2566cb39-d9fg-5ad6-tryb-d1e2kl067a89/'. Did
>   not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'null' or
>   validationParameters.ValidIssuers:
>   'https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/'.
>
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()
> >     Stack Query Cookies Headers
> >     SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer:
> >     'https://sts.windows.net/2096cb39-d9fd-4ad6-bbeb-d1e2be067a89/'. Did
> >     not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'null' or
> >     validationParameters.ValidIssuers:
> >     'https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/'.
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> >     task)
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> >     task)
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+d__9.MoveNext()
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+d__9.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> >     task)
> >     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

Below is the startup.cs code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using LPPlusUI.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging;
    namespace LPPlusUI
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddCookie();
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
                services.AddSession(options => {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//You can set Time   
                });
                services.AddMvc();
                services.AddPaging();
                var connection = @"string";
                services.AddDbContext<LPPlusExamContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            }
            //This method gets called by the runtime.Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseBrowserLink();
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                }
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseSession();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
            }
        }
```

Below is the code from appsettings.json

```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AzureAd": {
        "ClientId": "141b2123-d239-3568a-a713-4d4fg5781f57",
        "Domain": "lpstaging.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "common",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "ClientSecret": "eVLSRM7yHjkjh678sghgjdGTh7shjkSgtGSU4=",
        "AppIDURL": "https://lpstaging.onmicrosoft.com/<app-id>",
        "ConfigView": "MVC"
      }
    }
```

Comment: For multi-tenant applications general guidance is to keep default issuer validation turned off.. instead the application needs to have custom logic to validate issuer based on whatever it considers as the valid tenants.. Here is a sample you can look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Comment: Rohit is absolutely correct. In the general multi-tenant case you should turn off issuer validation. (or you can validate the format but that feels a bit unnecessary) If on the other hand the app is only meant to be used by some limited set of tenants that you know in advance, you should set them as the valid issuers.

Comment: How/Where do I keep default issuer validation turned off? Do I need to change in ConfigureServices? Can you help me with a code? Azure Sample is something different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working...

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    var azureadoptions = new AzureAdOptions(); Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", azureadoptions);
                    options.ClientId = $"{azureadoptions.ClientId}";
                    options.Authority = $"{azureadoptions.Instance}{azureadoptions.TenantId}";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidAudience = $"{azureadoptions.ClientId}",
                        //ValidAudiences = new List<string> { $"{azureadoptions.ClientId}", $"api://{azureadoptions.ClientId}", $"https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/" },
                        //ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{azureadoptions.ClientId}/" // for "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg" or "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
                        //ValidIssuer = $"{azureadoptions.Instance}{azureadoptions.TenantId}" // for "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
                        //ValidIssuers = new List<string> { $"https://sts.windows.net/{azureadoptions.TenantId}/", $"{azureadoptions.Instance}{azureadoptions.TenantId}/v2.0" }                        
                    };
                    //Log.LogInformation($"the AddJwtBearer options have been configured for ClientId = {azureadoptions.ClientId}");
                })
                .AddCookie();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the solution, this was really helpful. I would like to add my bit of understanding to this.

The TenantId should be "common"
and the issuer should be set to "false".

```
TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidAudience = clientId,
}
```

Only this much change in the code is required to enable multitenant access to your app service.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just had the same issue, but in my example the path was: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet&tabs=windows