# Azure AD multi-tenant login not working .NET 6

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, microsoft-entra-id

I have registered my application in Azure Entra ID (Azure Active Directory) as an multi-tenant application.

I'm not able to login with authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`, but it's working fine with authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0`.

When I try to authenticate with 'common', I'm getting an error related to issuer validation.

> Error: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/issuer-validation

Can someone help me to figure out what am I missing?

Let me know if you want any specific details for this.

Thanks in advance

Please refer to the screenshots here:
TokenValidation I'm checking only if I'm not using 'common' for authority.
[image]

.NET 6 `program.cs`:

[image: .NET 6 Program.cs file]

Azure Portal configuration for application:

[image: Azure Portal configuration for application]

Comment: Did you set `ValidateIssuer = false`?

Comment: @Rukmini I'm adding one more Image for this.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616457/multitenant-web-app-with-asp-net-core-sign-in-issue

Comment: Thanks @Rukmini, the question you mentioned, this also gave me more clarity with the flow of multi-tenant and single-tenant Token Validation parameters. However, my issue is now resolved, and I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Actually the 'If' condition I have applied before checking validation was causing the issue, because that was preventing the TokenValidation code from executing. just removed that, and its working fine.
[image]